# ensureCapacity() for inner ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a 2-dimensional `ArrayList` Object

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Short>> VOL_2D = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Short>>();
```

Now I want to call `.ensureCapacity()` on both the outer list and all the inner lists (The number of inner lists is know, but they are not initialized yet). For the outer list it is easy, I just define how many inner lists I want to fit inside.

Is there a nice way of calling this method on the inner lists? Or do I have to call it every time I initialize a new inner list?

Comment: what do you mean by 'not initialized yet' ?

Comment: How are you going to call a method on an object that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no thing like "2-dimensional ArrayList Object". You have an `ArrayList` which stores `ArrayList` objects inside it. All of objects stored in the outer list may have different sizes, some of them may be `null` or subclasses of `ArrayList`. So you have to explicitly *add* enough `ArrayList` objects into the outer array list:

```
int n = // size of the outer list
int m = // size of the inner lists
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Short>> VOL_2D = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Short>>(n);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    VOL_2D.add(new ArrayList<>(m));
```

Please note that `ensureCapacity` does not actually add any elements to the list. It just resizes the internal array to fit the specified number of elements, so subsequent resizes will not be necessary. Creating an empty `ArrayList` and calling `ensureCapacity` right after this is meaningless: better to use the `ArrayList(minCapacity)` constructor which will do the same in more effective way. Anyways `ensureCapacity` is useful just to improve the performance. If you actually want to have elements inside these lists, you may use:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    ArrayList<Short> inner = new ArrayList<>(m);
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
        inner.add(null); // or some other initial value
    VOL_2D.add(inner);
}
```

Finally if you want to have two-dimensional `ArrayList` of fixed size, why not just create array like this?

```
private short[][] VOL_2D = new short[n][m];
```

It would be much more performant.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't understand what this construct really means. You see, those "inner" lists have no idea that they might be collected in some outer list. So there is **no** way to (easily) achieve what you are looking for.

One possibility though: you could extend ArrayList; and in your own class, you can overwrite all methods that would "add" an ArrayList ... you can do whatever you want; for example set the desired capcity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `ensureCapacity`

It's just a method used for optimisation to avoid unnecessary reallocation of the underlying array data structure.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

> An application can increase the capacity of an ArrayList instance
>   before adding a large number of elements using the ensureCapacity
>   operation. This may reduce the amount of incremental reallocation.

Answer (score 0):

If the outer ArrayList size is known, and fixed then I would recommend you to use array instead of ArrayList, like below.

```
int size = 10;

ArrayList<Short>[] VOL_2D = new ArrayList<Short>[size];
```

Why do you need to call `ensureCapacity(int minCapacity)`? Could you elaborate your usecase? Because when you create instance you can specify the size of ArrayList. like below

```
VOL_2D[0] = new ArrayList<Short>(30);
```

This will invoke below constructor, and create an array size of 30

```
 public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
        super();
        if (initialCapacity < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                               initialCapacity);
        this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
    }
```

To answer your question, there is no single in-built method which will iterate all elements in list and call ensureCapacity.

You need to write code for this, like below

```
for(ArrayList<Short> vol : VOL_2D){
   vol.ensureCapacity(30);
}
```

Remember this, before call ensureCapacity method, you need to initialize your ArrayList object (in your case all inner ArrayList object), otherwise you will end up with NullPointerException.